# Do the set of "Concepts" contain itself?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, terminology, concept, set-theory

So I gather that a set containing itself is [not allowed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/253823). Yet it seems like a set of all concepts (*Concepts*) should contain an element denoting the idea of "concept". Is it that there is a difference of type re. "Concepts" and "concept"? Or is the element "concept" different in kind to other elements? Both seem unsatisfactory. Is this then a special case, and are there others?

Comment: In **some** Axiomatic Set Theories a "set containing itself is not allowed". There are others allowing it; see [Non-well-founded set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory)

Comment: What is a "concept" in AST ?  Maybe a [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)). If so, there is no *set* of classes.

Comment: There is a concept of a set, but the set itself is not a concept. So your set does not contain itself, not that there is anything wrong with that in principle.

Comment: Notice the slip: At first, you treat concepts as extensional entities and make them members of a set. Then, treat them as intensional. There's nothing wrong about "concept of concept" just as there's nothing about "meaning of meaning."

Comment: @Conifold You don't think every set is also a concept?

Comment: @TankutBeygu You may have something here, could you maybe expand to an answer?

Comment: Surely a handful of apples is distinct from the corresponding concept. In set theory sets are extensional and "concepts" are the one-place predicates their elements satisfy.

Comment: @christo183 Bereft of rigour, just to be suggestive: The container metaphor works, if it does, when we talk in extensional mode; a container that contains itself strikes us as unintelligible. Consider what is (or, are) wrong with the following sentence: "natural numbers = {0, 1, 2, ..., a natural number}, certainly, for a natural number is a member of the set of natural numbers."

Comment: @Conifold isn't a hand full of apples the extensional definition of *Hand full of apples*?

Comment: And how does that turn the extension, i.e. apples, into the concept defined? Are you suggesting that the concept of 3-apple set has 3 apples in it?

Comment: @TankutBeygu I hear you. The elements of the set must be extensional? But then the set of concepts can contain an element that is recursively the set of concepts.

Comment: @Conifold Are you saying the signifier "*Concept*", as opposed to is referent, is not a concept?

Comment: It is your turn to answer first.

Comment: @Conifold I do see the difference between signified and referent so no a concept doesn't contain material apples. But surely the signified is inherently a concept?

Comment: Does it contain ideal apples then, is that the "signified"? Because the concept of 3-apple set does not contain those either, inherently or otherwise. I think you are just collapsing the usual correspondence between objects, their concepts and their names into an "identity".

Comment: @Conifold The signified is the idea or concept according to de Saussure. While the referent would be the actual apples... Note that for apples there is no problem since the set is exclusively defined, there can be no pears or definitions or concepts in the set. But for *Concepts* the intention is specifically for concepts.

Comment: You need to lay out your argument for "set is a concept" more systematically, with the relevance of Saussure's scheme (he was not doing set theory), intention, signifieds, etc., spelled out. With these unfinished snippets I can not shake off the "so what" reaction. Why the difference in the intention for concepts vs apples matters to the issue is murky.

Comment: @Conifold "the concept of 3-apple set" must be a member of *Concepts* so why not the concept of *Concepts*, or the concept of the referent of *Concepts*, or the concept of the idea of a concept?

Comment: 'Metaphor' is a meta metaphor. And meaning doesn't mean what we mean it to mean, because answers aren't the answer.

Comment: Sure, but the concept of 3-apple set is no more a 3-apple set than the concept of apple is an apple. If you want self-reference so much why not simply say that the concept of  concept falls under itself, without dragging sets into it. The concept of vague concept also falls under itself. And "word" is itself a word. But again, so what?

Comment: @Conifold In trying to use set theory to illuminate the self referential nature of concept I found more concepts kept popping up. Apples and words expressly excludes their own intension from the set while *Concepts* seem unsatisfiable. So what? I just think it is neat how *Concepts* can be such a rich and enormous set.

Answer (score 1):

Mauro's first comment is a perfectly fine answer.  I'll expand upon it.

In informal set theory, a set is an unordered collection of things.  While a list has order and might have duplicates, a set either contains a thing or it does not.  Informally, people could just define sets by describing which things are in them.  Some examples:

- A: The set of all integers
- B: The set of one-digit decimal integers.
- C: The set of subsets of B which contain three elements.  For example, {2,3,4} and {0,6,8}.
- D: The set of sets that do not contain other sets.  B is an example.
- E: The set of sets that do contain other sets.  C is an example.

Unfortunately, this informal set theory led to complications, as Russell noted.  The phrase "the set of all sets that do not contain themselves" appears to be a valid set description, but it is not, as that would lead to a paradox.

There have been multiple ways of formalizing set theory to avoid such problems.  In some of them, sets cannot contain other sets, but in others, they can.  See Mauro's comment on the question for links to more details.

A "set" is a "concept", so the "Set of concepts" would indeed contain itself, assuming it exists.  If the formalization you are working with would not allow it, then the set does not exist.  If it does exist, then it would certainly contain itself.